# M2E Pro uploading greyed-out images to eBay listings

Tags: magento, litespeed, m2e-pro

Currently running Magento Pro 1.12.0.0
M2E Pro Version: 5.2.3.r4567

As stated above, any time the client lists products on eBay from Magento using the extension M2E Pro, the images - usually the primary image - is either fully or partially greyed.

They can fix this by going into eBay and reuploading the greyed images but it is a pain and very time consuming for them. The result resembles a jpg that has been interrupted during upload or download - part of the image will show.

There is no consistency. I've experimented with a set of 50kb images and a set of 85kb images. I received varied results. I attributed this varience to some sort of server memory cap so I raised the PHP memory limit with no success.

M2E Pro support team was unable to help and I can't find anyone else online experiencing this issue online so here's hoping! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After evaluating the full web stack and disabling/enabling individual layers, was able to narrow it down to a bug in LiteSpeed - their Apache alternative. Apparently a common occurrence for their current version:

http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/showthread.php?t=5870

As opposed to downgrading as the forum member did, I completely removed LiteSpeed and will most likely be loading Varnish in its place. Marking this as solved and tagging with "LiteSpeed" for the benefit of any of its users experiencing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where even eBay wasn't able to help me.

Just make sure, that the images you are uploading are not CMYK, they need to be in RGB.
I also changed all images to jpg, because there were severe issues with transparent png on eBay.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out today and examine the images. I'll let you know what I come across.

Comment: I am still working on this solution. It appears my hottest lead as of the moment may be the fact that user is running LiteSpeed web server. I've come across a single thread online from another M2E user. Should have a final answer this week when we switch the client to Nginx.

Comment: eBay only has a problem with the server if it is timing out.